# Upload Multiple Files In PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

Using some excellent online tutorials I've put together the code below which allows a user to upload image files to a server folder and the filename and other details to a mySQL database.

**PHP Script**

```
<?php
//define a maxim size for the uploaded images
//define ("MAX_SIZE","100"); 
// define the width and height for the thumbnail
// note that theese dimmensions are considered the maximum dimmension and are not fixed, 
// because we have to keep the image ratio intact or it will be deformed
define ("WIDTH","150"); 
define ("HEIGHT","100"); 

// this is the function that will create the thumbnail image from the uploaded image
// the resize will be done considering the width and height defined, but without deforming the image
function make_thumb($img_name,$filename,$new_w,$new_h)
{
//get image extension.
$ext=getExtension($img_name);
//creates the new image using the appropriate function from gd library
if(!strcmp("jpg",$ext) || !strcmp("jpeg",$ext))
$src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($img_name);

if(!strcmp("png",$ext))
$src_img=imagecreatefrompng($img_name);

//gets the dimmensions of the image
$old_x=imageSX($src_img);
$old_y=imageSY($src_img);

// next we will calculate the new dimmensions for the thumbnail image
// the next steps will be taken: 
// 1. calculate the ratio by dividing the old dimmensions with the new ones
// 2. if the ratio for the width is higher, the width will remain the one define in WIDTH variable
// and the height will be calculated so the image ratio will not change
// 3. otherwise we will use the height ratio for the image
// as a result, only one of the dimmensions will be from the fixed ones
$ratio1=$old_x/$new_w;
$ratio2=$old_y/$new_h;
if($ratio1>$ratio2) {
$thumb_w=$new_w;
$thumb_h=$old_y/$ratio1;
}
else {
$thumb_h=$new_h;
$thumb_w=$old_x/$ratio2;
}

// we create a new image with the new dimmensions
$dst_img=ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);

// resize the big image to the new created one
imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y); 

// output the created image to the file. Now we will have the thumbnail into the file named by $filename
if(!strcmp("png",$ext))
imagepng($dst_img,$filename); 
else
imagejpeg($dst_img,$filename); 

//destroys source and destination images. 
imagedestroy($dst_img); 
imagedestroy($src_img); 
}

// This function reads the extension of the file. 
// It is used to determine if the file is an image by checking the extension. 
function getExtension($str) {
$i = strrpos($str,".");
if (!$i) { return ""; }
$l = strlen($str) - $i;
$ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
return $ext;
}
$title = ($_POST['title']); 

if ($title == '') // if title is not set 
$title = '(No Title Provided)';// use (empty title) string 
//reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];

if ($image) 
{
// get the original name of the file from the clients machine
$filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

// get the extension of the file in a lower case format
$extension = getExtension($filename);
$extension = strtolower($extension);
// if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error, print an error message 
//and will not upload the file, otherwise we continue
if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png")) 
{
echo '<b> Error! </b> - The image that you attempted to upload is not in the correct format. The file format <b> must </b> be one of the following: <b> "jpg", "jpeg" </b> or <b> "png" </b>. Please try again.';
$errors=1;
}
else
{
// get the size of the image in bytes
// $_FILES[\'image\'][\'tmp_name\'] is the temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
$size=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$sizekb=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

//compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
if ($sizekb > 1150000)
{
echo '<b> Error! </b> - The file that you are attempting to upload is greater than the prescribed <b> 1MB </b> limit. Please try again.';
$errors=1;
}

//we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
$image_name=time().'.'.$title.'.'.$extension;
//the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)
$newname="images/".$image_name;
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
if (!$copied) 
{
//echo '<b> Error! </b> Your file has not been loaded';
//$errors=1;
}
else
{
// the new thumbnail image will be placed in images/thumbs/ folder
$thumb_name='images/thumbs/'.$image_name;
// call the function that will create the thumbnail. The function will get as parameters 
//the image name, the thumbnail name and the width and height desired for the thumbnail
$thumb=make_thumb($newname,$thumb_name,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
} }}

//If no errors registred, print the success message and show the thumbnail image created
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
{
//echo '<br><b> Success! </b> - Your image has been uploaded</br>';
//echo '<img src="'.$thumb_name.'">';
}
require("mapmyfindsdbinfo.php");
// Gets data from form
$userid = $_POST["userid"];
$locationid = $_POST["locationid"];
$findosgb36lat = $_POST["findosgb36lat"];
$findosgb36lon = $_POST["findosgb36lon"];
$dateoftrip = $_POST["dateoftrip"];
$findcategory = $_POST["findcategory"];
$findname = $_POST["findname"];
$finddescription = $_POST["finddescription"];
$detectorid= $_POST["detectorname"];
$searchheadid = $_POST["searchheadname"];
if( empty($_POST["detectorsettings"]) ) {     
$detectorsettings = 'No details provided.'; } else {     
$detectorsettings = $_POST["detectorsettings"]; } 
if( empty($_POST["pasref"]) ) {     
$pasref = 'No PAS Ref. number provided.'; } else {     
$pasref = $_POST["pasref"]; } 
if( empty($_POST["additionalcomments"]) ) {     
$additionalcomments = 'No additional comments made.'; } else {     
$additionalcomments = $_POST["additionalcomments"]; } 
$makepublic = $_POST["makepublic"];

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$conn = mysql_connect ("hostname", $username, $password);
if (!$conn) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $conn);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO finds (userid, locationid, findosgb36lat, findosgb36lon, dateoftrip, findcategory, findname, finddescription, detectorid, searchheadid, detectorsettings, pasref, additionalcomments, makepublic) VALUES ('$userid', '$locationid', '$findosgb36lat', '$findosgb36lon', '$dateoftrip', '$findcategory', '$findname', '$finddescription', '$detectorid', '$searchheadid', '$detectorsettings', '$pasref', '$additionalcomments', '$makepublic')";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

$findid = mysql_insert_id($conn);

$sql = "INSERT INTO testimages (title, imagename, findid) VALUES ('$title', '$image_name', '$findid')";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

**HTML Form**

```
<form name="savemyfindstolocation" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="savemyfindstolocation.php">
    <p align="left">Do You Wish To Add Find Images<label></label>
        <label></label>
    </p>
    <div align="left">
        <table id="addfiletable" border="1" style="table-layout:auto">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><div align="center">Title</div></td>
                <td><div align="center">File Location </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20"><input name="select" type="radio" id="select" title=""/></td>
                <td width="144"><input name="title" type="text" id="title"/></td>
                <td width="314"><input name="image" type="file" id="image" onchange="addRow();" size="40"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div align="justify">
            <input type="submit" name="deleterow" value="Delete Row" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />        
</form>
```

It all works well, but I'd now like to extend the functionality of allowing a user to upload more than 1 file at a time. I've done a fair bit of research to look at how to upload multiple files, but I'm fairly new to PHP and a little unsure as to which is the best way to progress this.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps have a look at what I've put together and offer some guidance on how I can change this to upload mutiple files upon the form submit.

Many thanks

Comment: Because of Google and Wordpress are using Adobe Flash for multiple file uploads I think it isn't possible using just PHP.

Comment: I hope your PHP file indentation is better than what's shown here. Also, your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Hi, yes I know my PHP isn;t particualrly tidy, it's something I'm working on.

Comment: @sharethis: PHP does support multiple file uploads. A probable reason for Google and Wordpress to use Flash (I didn't check whether they do that) is that the HTTP protocol is not very well suited for file uploads. There's no progress indication, to name something.

Comment: @IRHM work on your indentation as you go; it's much easier to get it right first time :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PHP**

```
foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $i => $name)
{
    // now $name holds the original file name
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $error = $_FILES['image']['error'][$i];
    $size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];
    $type = $_FILES['image']['type'][$i];

    if($error === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
    {
        $extension = getExtension($name);
        if( ! in_array(strtolower($extension, array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png') )
        {
            // Error, invalid extension detected
        }
        else if ($size > $maxAllowedFileSize /* needs to be defined elsewhere */)
        {
            // Error, file too large
        }
        else
        {
            // No errors
            $newFileName = 'foo'; // You'll probably want something unique for each file.
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $newFileName))
            {
                // Uploaded file successfully moved to new location
                $thumbName = 'thumb_image_name';
                $thumb = make_thumb($newFileName, $thumbName, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="image[]" type="file" class="image-upload" />
    <input name="image[]" type="file" class="image-upload" />
    <input name="image[]" type="file" class="image-upload" />
    <input name="image[]" type="file" class="image-upload" />
    <input name="image[]" type="file" class="image-upload" />

    <!-- You need to add more, including a submit button -->
</form>
```

Note the name of the input elements. The `[]` at the end cause PHP to create an array and add the items to the array.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. Here's the link to the manual I was going to add: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: That's a helpful link, I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Both many thanks for this, it's a great help. The only issue I have is that I'm dynamically creating each row in the table, so the 'Input Name' is unqiue. From what I've read and hopefully understood in addition to the help you've given me, am I right in thinking that the only way in which I can send multiple files is to have a predefined number of rows available rather than dynamically added? Kind regards

Comment: You can still use `name="input[]"` even when you add the rows dynamically. You can also use `name="title[]"` for your title input fields. Just note that the `id`s must be unique. But you could simply leave the `id`s out.

Comment: @Arjan, I'm very sorry to trouble you especially as you've already been so helpful. I feel really stupid, but I've changed the table on my form to include the array, but I've been trying to add the PHP code you provided, and I just can't seem to get this to work. Using my original code, albeit badly formatted, could you tell me please where I would need to insert your additional PHP code into my script. I am relatively new to PHP so please bear with me. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM: I've added my answer so it contains more information on how to process the uploaded files. That should also help you in locating where that part needs to be in your script. It also shows how proper indenting can help. Besides, when procesing uploaded files you should use `move_uploaded_file`, not `copy`.

Comment: @Arjan BTW, you're missing `_`s before each FILES.