# php uploading multiple files halts on error check

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload multiple files, by altering a script I once used to upload a single file.

The only changes I've made are to add more file input fields to the form. But when I submit the form to the script, it halts at where I check for errors. How do I proceed with multiple files?

```
$form  = '<form action="imgProcess.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
$form .= '<div><input type="file" name="file[]"></div>';
$form .= '<div><input type="file" name="file[]"></div>';
$form .= '<div><input type="file" name="file[]"></div>';
$form .= '<div><input type="file" name="file[]"></div>';
$form .= '<div><input type="file" name="file[]"></div>';
$form .= '<input type="hidden" name="handle" value="testHandle" />';
$form .= '<input type="submit">';
$form .= '</form>';
```

**imgProcess.php**

```
if($_FILES && isset($_POST['handle'])) {

    $numFiles = count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    echo $numFiles;

    $handle = $_POST['handle'];

    echo $handle;

    // Halt on errors
    if($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {


    } else {
        echo 'There were errors<br>';
        print_r( $_FILES['file']['error'] );
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error 1';
}

//
There were errors
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 4 [3] => 4 [4] => 4 )
```

Comment: So, where are the files supposed to be "uploaded" to? Are you not using [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)?

Comment: That comes later in the script... First check for errors, then proceed. that's how I do it...

Comment: Have a look at the Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/9046657/ found under "Related". You may spend less time using another script. You'll definitely need a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Ah! Didn't see your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You have 5 elements of file.

Whereas the status-code in error msg you have printed shows that you have uploaded only two files.

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 4 [3] => 4 [4] => 4 )
                                 ^        ^        ^
```

Rest of them were kept empty and you submitted the form.
Refer [***`this`***](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) to understand the details.

This is what is giving error.
You might have to handle it differently so that it considers only the files that you have uploaded.

Comment: You're correct, I uploaded only 2. So error `4` says no file was uploaded. I'm totally new to this file uploading thing. How do I handle this? `$numFiles` is always `5` even if I upload `2`.

Answer (score 1):

you can add attribute "multiple" to your input field, instead of adding many input fields. in official php site you can find example how upload multiple files

Answer (score 1):

from all files if you want to upload those files that do not have any error then use try and catch and if you want to throw error if any one of them is having error then change your condition to check error like this

```
$fileUploadError = array_filter($_FILES['file']['error']);

if(count($fileUploadError) > 0 ) { 

     echo "error";    
} else {

     echo "no error";    
}
```

hope this might help you

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
    $error=$_FILES['file']['error'];

for($i=0;$i<$numFiles;$i++)
{
     if($error[$i] == 0) {

        //your code
    } 
}
```

Comment: For some strange reason, $numFiles is always `5` even if I upload `2` files. Any way to get around this?

Comment: `$numFiles = count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);`

This will count all the inputs you have. eventhough no file is uploaded

use `if($_FILES['file']['size'] > 0)` to check whether a file is uploaded